# Unable to update bind in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, upgrade, bind

I am trying to update bind in centos using this command.

```
$ sudo yum update bind
```

Getting this error

```
Transaction check error:   file /usr/libexec/setup-named-chroot.sh from install of bind-chroot-32:9.9.4-61.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package bind-sdb-chroot-32:9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
```

Details

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bind.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: bind = 32:9.9.4-51.el7 for package: 32:bind-pkcs11-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: bind = 32:9.9.4-51.el7 for package: 32:bind-chroot-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
---> Package bind.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: bind-libs = 32:9.9.4-61.el7 for package: 32:bind-9.9.4-61.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bind-chroot.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
---> Package bind-chroot.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: bind-libs = 32:9.9.4-51.el7 for package: 32:bind-devel-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: bind-libs = 32:9.9.4-51.el7 for package: 32:bind-sdb-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: bind-libs = 32:9.9.4-51.el7 for package: 32:bind-pkcs11-libs-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: bind-libs = 32:9.9.4-51.el7 for package: 32:bind-utils-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: bind-license = 32:9.9.4-61.el7 for package: 32:bind-libs-9.9.4-61.el7.x86_64
---> Package bind-pkcs11.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
---> Package bind-pkcs11.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bind-devel.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
---> Package bind-devel.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
---> Package bind-license.noarch 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: bind-license = 32:9.9.4-51.el7 for package: 32:bind-libs-lite-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
---> Package bind-license.noarch 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
---> Package bind-pkcs11-libs.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: bind-pkcs11-libs = 32:9.9.4-51.el7 for package: 32:bind-pkcs11-utils-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: bind-pkcs11-libs = 32:9.9.4-51.el7 for package: 32:bind-pkcs11-devel-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
---> Package bind-pkcs11-libs.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
---> Package bind-sdb.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
---> Package bind-sdb.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bind-libs-lite.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: bind-libs-lite = 32:9.9.4-51.el7 for package: 32:bind-lite-devel-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
---> Package bind-libs-lite.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
---> Package bind-pkcs11-devel.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
---> Package bind-pkcs11-devel.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
---> Package bind-pkcs11-utils.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
---> Package bind-pkcs11-utils.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bind-lite-devel.x86_64 32:9.9.4-51.el7 will be updated
---> Package bind-lite-devel.x86_64 32:9.9.4-61.el7 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

============================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                Arch                                        Version                                                 Repository                                 Size
============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 bind                                                   x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                      1.8 M
Updating for dependencies:
 bind-chroot                                            x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                       87 k
 bind-devel                                             x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                      399 k
 bind-libs                                              x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                      1.0 M
 bind-libs-lite                                         x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                      734 k
 bind-license                                           noarch                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                       85 k
 bind-lite-devel                                        x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                      308 k
 bind-pkcs11                                            x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                      298 k
 bind-pkcs11-devel                                      x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                      105 k
 bind-pkcs11-libs                                       x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                      1.1 M
 bind-pkcs11-utils                                      x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                      198 k
 bind-sdb                                               x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                      353 k
 bind-utils                                             x86_64                                      32:9.9.4-61.el7                                         base                                      204 k

Transaction Summary
============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade  1 Package (+12 Dependent packages)

Total size: 6.6 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /usr/libexec/setup-named-chroot.sh from install of bind-chroot-32:9.9.4-61.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package bind-sdb-chroot-32:9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

Installed Packages Information

```
32:bind-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = 1b77b76443d842c156c6c888bc9c0735ff4f8f7cbdbd2e4fb2dcecb03833a042
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind bind-utils -y
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1506987578
     from_repo_timestamp = 1506987830
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://mirror.san.fastserv.com/pub/linux/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-chroot-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = e58293072f5aeb6082a1a8e62f18d66a882b7a8aa224a5d6234945a83be1d9bf
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind*
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1510935926
     from_repo_timestamp = 1510936321
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://mirror.sigmanet.com/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-chroot-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-devel-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = ee5b0d89888964680e42ddba18b4c95dabb96360f2a38a55cd84dbd1dfe2839e
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind*
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1510935926
     from_repo_timestamp = 1510936321
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://linux.cc.lehigh.edu/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-devel-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

bind-dyndb-ldap-11.1-4.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = 8f33bcdbc883179beeeff80124ab85a3e51ac1f25d020560765c5520298bf3d3
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind*
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1510935926
     from_repo_timestamp = 1510936321
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://mirror.atlantic.net/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-dyndb-ldap-11.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-libs-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     changed_by = 1000
     checksum_data = b0630f026c8ad1e6b03e757895466c2dc82af85e810c477f25ddef1332322a8c
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind bind-utils -y
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1506987578
     from_repo_timestamp = 1506987830
     installed_by = 4294967295
     reason = dep
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-libs-lite-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     changed_by = 1000
     checksum_data = cd27101f3bfe45e4dd9cde2e9d72298ada09c205aedbb280b4b16c5796b68d2d
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind bind-utils -y
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1506987578
     from_repo_timestamp = 1506987830
     installed_by = 4294967295
     reason = dep
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-license-9.9.4-51.el7.noarch
     changed_by = 1000
     checksum_data = 88012038d30a8c2af898e885e857753a2a6dcae2a24b37e78233b2a5cf2faae3
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind bind-utils -y
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1506987578
     from_repo_timestamp = 1506987830
     installed_by = 4294967295
     origin_url = http://linux.cc.lehigh.edu/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-license-9.9.4-51.el7.noarch.rpm
     reason = dep
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-lite-devel-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = 48f8a49a979fc4863ea933db6b8a5d6788cfb1ec13cd2accd1cbb707c79683d9
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind*
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1510935926
     from_repo_timestamp = 1510936321
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-lite-devel-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-pkcs11-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = 8b3d84f4467dc9a78d90803feabe86c587ddf85636e81373445047dfc2f9d25b
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind*
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1510935926
     from_repo_timestamp = 1510936321
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://mirrors.tripadvisor.com/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-pkcs11-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-pkcs11-devel-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = 47e16dffd439f079ebbe21d81256923b67a20460685e8c40d9c534dbdef73fee
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind*
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1510935926
     from_repo_timestamp = 1510936321
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://mirror.sigmanet.com/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-pkcs11-devel-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-pkcs11-libs-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = fff99f3f69933bef1e37a8cbc3e4b04c1b37d16fa844c55f4ce1649bc49c1ad2
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind*
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1510935926
     from_repo_timestamp = 1510936321
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://mirror.sigmanet.com/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-pkcs11-libs-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-pkcs11-utils-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = 446d074072063172ddd4e60f949b4d7d91258ddc6d2f1d5adcba53f142d564b6
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind*
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1510935926
     from_repo_timestamp = 1510936321
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://mirror.sigmanet.com/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-pkcs11-utils-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-sdb-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = 12da8b3c7b63cb2f7cab21f444d6fbaf6db76e0552281a9a30f9e91716425a60
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind*
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1510935926
     from_repo_timestamp = 1510936321
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://mirror.sigmanet.com/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-sdb-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-sdb-chroot-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = c11178ad4948e15f3f1b96cb4d21a45b7d9ea899bb01e50dc5d0a709ae8b1b59
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind*
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1510935926
     from_repo_timestamp = 1510936321
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://mirror.sigmanet.com/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-sdb-chroot-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

32:bind-utils-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64
     changed_by = 1000
     checksum_data = 25b6002054aff619ad803df1f883bfad37dc1565ffa33511b09a3af449d3f433
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind bind-utils -y
     from_repo = updates
     from_repo_revision = 1506987578
     from_repo_timestamp = 1506987830
     installed_by = 4294967295
     origin_url = http://centos.vwtonline.net/centos/7.4.1708/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-utils-9.9.4-51.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633

bindfs-1.13.7-3.el7.x86_64
     checksum_data = 8becb7be67e1c9429c543bbf0bc088527f5121bca964b636838ebc10a738f83d
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install bind*
     from_repo = epel
     from_repo_revision = 1511032237
     from_repo_timestamp = 1511035134
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = http://mirror.seas.harvard.edu/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/b/bindfs-1.13.7-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = cd5d7927-7fb0-48bf-9cbc-77c5d3532633
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CentOS but are you supposed to have both bind and bind-sdb installed at the same time on your system? What happens if you do `yum update bind-sdb`?

Comment: @lgeorget  Using `yum update bind-sdb`, I got the same error.

Comment: And with `yum update bind-sdb-chroot`?

Comment: @lgeorget With `yum update bind-sdb-chroot`, I got the same error

Comment: Wierd, so there are apparently two packages that are scheduled to be installed at the same time but which conflict on a file. That could be a bug in the packages.

Comment: Is there any option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it this file `/usr/libexec/setup-named-chroot.sh` was previously packaged in `bind-chroot` but was moved to `bind-sdb-chroot`. Since we're assessing what happened it's safe to attempt to force things along.

For starters I'd do a `upgrade` rather than an `update`:

```
$ sudo yum upgrade
```

This will remove any obsolete packages which might be leading to your conflicts here. If you still run into issues, I'd remove the 2 problem packages, then do the update, then reinstall them. This will likely be the easiest way to work around the packaging issue(s) you're bumping up against.

```
$ sudo yum remove bind-chroot bind-sdb-chroot
$ sudo yum update
$ sudo yum install bind-chroot bind-sdb-chroot
```

#### Looks like you found a bug

If you install both packages you'll uncover the following scenario which should never happen with package management:

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/libexec/setup-named-chroot.sh
bind-sdb-chroot-9.9.4-61.el7.x86_64
bind-chroot-9.9.4-61.el7.x86_64
```

Both of these packages claim ownership of this file. It's curious that I was able to install both of these using `yum`.

#### Installing packages you don't need

The `bind-sdb` package seems unnecessary in your case, correct me if I'm wrong. That package is if you want to store your `bind` configuration in a SQL database, rather than flat files.

If you're just using `bind` with configuration files, then you don't even need this package in the first place. It's generally best to limit your installation of packages to things you actually need. The more packages you install, you increase the chances that you'll run into these types of issues.

Comment: You right, I found bind-sdb is useless, then I removed it.